# $\int_a^bf(x)p(x)\ dx = f(a)\int_a^c p(x)\ dx + f(b)\int_c^b p(x) \ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f,p:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be functions of class $C^1$. Show that if $f$ is crescent, there will exist $c\in [a,b]$ such that:

$$\int_a^bf(x)p(x)\ dx = f(a)\int_a^c p(x)\ dx + f(b)\int_c^b p(x) \ dx$$

I truly don't have any idea on how to solve it. I guess it has something to do with mean value theorem or something like that? $$f(b)-f(a) = f'(c)(b-a)$$

with $f'(c)>0$

but I wouldn't be able to prove an equality with that, just an inequality.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Are you aware of the mean value theorem for Riemann Stieltjes integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function
\begin{align}
F(x) := f(a)\int^x_a p(t)\ dt + f(b)\int^b_x p(t)\ dt.
\end{align}
Observe $F(b) = f(a)\int^b_ap(t)\ dt $ and $F(a) = f(b)\int^b_a p(t)\ dt$. Since $f'>0$ then this means
\begin{align}
 F(b)=f(a) \int^b_a p(t)\ dt \leq \int^b_a f(t)p(t)\ dt \leq f(b) \int^b_a p(t)\ dt=F(a).
\end{align}
Apply intermediate value theorem to see there exists $c \in(a, b)$ such that 
\begin{align}
F(c) = \int^b_a f(t)p(t)\ dt.
\end{align}

Note: I made an assumption that $p \geq 0$ on $[a, b]$.